# fasta file reading python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I am reading a FASTA file that has a format like this:

```
>gi|31563518|ref|NP_852610.1| microtubule-associated proteins 1A/1B light chain 3A isoform b [Homo sapiens]
MKMRFFSSPCGKAAVDPADRCKEVQQIRDQHPSKIPVIIERYKGEKQLPVLDKTKFLVPDHVNMSELVKIIRRRLQLNPTQAFFLLVNQHSMVSVSTPIADIYEQEKDEDGFLYMVYASQETFGF
```

I have to read the file and then calculate the JC distance (For a pair of sequences, the JC distance is -3/4 * ln(1 - 4/3 * p), where p is the proportion of sites that differ between the pair)

I have set up the skeleton of it but am unsure how to do the rest.  AFter reading and calculating the JukesCantor distance I have to write it to a new output file and it should be in a table
any help i can get is much appreciated! thanks, new to python AND fasta files

```
def readData():
    filename = input("Enter the name of the FASTA file: ")
    infile = open(filename, "r")

def CalculateJC(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 # temporary*

def calcDists(seqs):
    output = []
    for seq1 in seqs:
        newrow = []
        for seq2 in seqs:
            dist = calculateJS(seq1,seq2)
            newrow.append(dist)
        output.append(newrow)
        list(enumerate(seasons))
    return output


def outputDists(distMat):
    pass

def main():
    seqs = readData()
    distMat = calcDists(seqs)
    outputDists(distMat)



if__name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Take a look at [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page). It supports reading and writing of fasta files.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking too many questions at a time! Focus on one.

Reading and writing FASTA files is covered in [BioPython](http://biopython.org/) (as suggested in comments).

I noticed that you aren't calculating your JC distance yet, so perhaps this is where you need help.
Here is what I came up with:

```
import itertools, math

def computeJC(seq1, seq2):
    equal = 0
    for base1, base2 in itertools.izip(seq1, seq2):
        equal += (base1 == base2)
    p = equal / float(len(seq1))     
    return -3/4 * math.log(1 - 4/3 * p)
```

The itertools.izip trick is explained here: [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)
This piece of code will work with any kind of string, and the look will stop when either seq1 or seq2 reaches the end.

Someone else may come up with a "Pythonic one-liner", but try to understand my approach first. It avoids the pitfalls that your code felt into: nested loops, unnecessary branching, runtime list growing, spaghetti code to name a few. Enjoy!